# Mass-move checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, checkbox

Lets say I have a bunch of `<li>`'s in a `<ul>`.  They are laid out like this:

```
<li class="gchoice_7_1">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_2">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_3">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_4">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_5">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_6">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_7">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_8">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_9">...</li>
<li class="gchoice_7_10">...</li>
```

However, I want to move them all into a different order, ie

```
1
4
2
8
7
3
etc...
```

I want to move a bunch of these around, and I COULD use

```
$('.gchoice_7_4').insertAfter($('.gchoice_7_1'));
```

but then I have to keep track of what's placed after what so I don't get into incorrectly placing them.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

**Update** I know the order because each of these `<li>`s are sorted in alphabetical order, i.e.

```
Academia, Admin/Assistant, Career, Full-Time
```

However, These checkboxes hold three different Wordpress Categories worth of checkboxes.  I want to put them in order based on what category parent they are in. i.e.

```
[Full-Time, Part-Time], [Academia, Admin/Assistant], [Early-Career, Mid-Career]
```

**Update 2** This is the specific order I want them in (there are 21 checkboxes from 1-23, excluding 10 and 20):

```
1,2,4,5,8,14,16,21,23,18

9,19,22,12

6,17,15
```

Then I want to hide `3,7,11,13`

I was wondering if there was an easy way to rearrange them, i.e. loop through and add a class of an incrementing number to the `<li>`'s and then set an array of what order they went in and then reorder them (keep the inner content in-tact too!).

Comment: how do you know what the new order is?

Comment: My apologies, I left that information out so it wouldn't be confusing/misleading. My post will be updated to explain how I know the order.

Comment: how does the checkboxes "hold three different Wordpress Categories"?

Comment: I'm using gravity forms and the gravity forms custom post type plugin.  I'm using a taxonomy that has hierarchical categories (Experience with children of Early-Career, Mid-Career, Late-Career)  But it also has a category of Interest with children like Academia, Admin/Assistant and others.  So essentially, I have a hierarchical taxonomy, but all gravity forms is doing is grabbing all of them without care of hierarchy and putting them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `ul` and move the `li` elements to that. Then, use the `replaceWith`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith)]</sup>* method to replace the original `ul`.

```
var lis = $('#origList li'),
    newOrder = [1, 0, 2], // The array indices are the old order.
                          // The array values are the new order.
                          // Modify this array to you needs.
    newList = $('<ul></ul>'),
    ii;

for (ii = 0; ii < newOrder.length; ii += 1) {
    newList.append(lis[newOrder[ii]]);
}

$('#origList').replaceWith(newList);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/TWkPW/

**UPDATE:** If you need to sort the `li` elements by their classes, just put the classes in the order you want in `newOrder` and filter `lis` by the class:

```
var lis = $('#origList li'),
    newOrder = ['.class2', '.class3', '.class1'],
    newList = $('<ul></ul>'),
    ii;

for (ii = 0; ii < newOrder.length; ii += 1) {
    newList.append(lis.filter(newOrder[ii]));
}

$('#origList').replaceWith(newList);
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't this mean I'll have to account for the missing 10th and 20th index? (_7_1 = 0 in the index, and _7_11 = 9th in the index?)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is much easier than using `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`, but is there a way you can have it append based on the class of the list items rather than what number they are in the index of list items?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original post, something like this?

```
var newOrder = [4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2];
var newUl = $('<ul>');
$.each(newOrder, function(key, value) {
    newUl.append($('#old').children('.gchoice_7_' + value).detach());
});
$('#old').remove();
$('#cont').append(newUl);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/jqEgM/7/

**Update:** You can then hide whatever li's you want following the same approach:

```
var hideOrder = [3, 7, 11, 13];
$.each(hideOrder, function(key) {
    newUl.children('.gchoice_7_' + key).hide();
});
```

Comment: I checked out your jsfiddle and it doesn't appear to sort them at all?

Comment: I'll fiddle (no pun intended) with your fiddle a bit more to see if I can get it to work, because it would be ideal if I could set a sort order based on the classname rather than the key in an index.

Comment: @Josh: Sorry I missed your updates as I was away. Sorting wasn't there in your OP, so my fiddle doesn't have that. DO you still need it or @FishBasketGordo's` answer good enough?

Comment: `@FishBasketGordo`'s is enough.  In my OP I DID state that I wanted the `<li>`'s in a different order and stated an order.  The only thing wrong with your answer is that the key is the index in the array, rather than the value at that index (therefore the first item in `newOrder` is 4, but when using `$.each()` the key is 0).

Comment: You're right. I need the `value` not the `key`. Also, I was away when you updated your post so I missed the sorting part.

Comment: Thanks for the code update.  Now it works exactly as I would have wanted to.  Definitely bookmarked for later use.